# How to view other language localization on iPhone?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

(on the surface this might not appear as a programming question but I think it does relate to testing).

Recently, I added the French localization for my app on iTunes Connect. The app was approved a while back and now I want to take a look at the French localization on my iPhone to see how it looks.

I've gone into settings, pulled up the account screen for my Apple ID, and set the Country / Region to France. Then I changed the phones language to French. When I go into the app store, the featured page is in French, however when I search for my app, the English localization still appears!

So my question is, how is it possible to view another languages localization on your own iPhone which is from a different country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey please have look below steps,

Testing App Localization

If you have created an app with multiple localizations, you can test them in iOS Simulator by changing the Internationalization settings.

To change the language of a simulation environment

Build and run your app in iOS Simulator.
Select the simulation environment whose settings you want to change by choosing Hardware > Version > iOS version.
Click the Home button to reveal the Home screen, and click Settings.
Go to General > International > Language.
Select the language, and click Done.
For more information on localizing your app, see Internationalization Programming Topics.

Ref. From : [**Apple doc**](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html)

you can same path found for device language change for this testing.

**Edit :**

For meta data localisation check. you have to access particular store by [**changing store**](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6119) from your apple itunes a/c.

Comment: I'm trying to look at the localized meta data (i.e. for the screen shots, app description) in the app store. I don't believe you can look at the app store on the simulator.

Comment: for that you have to change store of your a/c. Please chech updated ans.

Comment: Does that work for you when you do it? For me I've done it, but it's still showing English.

Comment: if possible then provide app name.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, what I was doing actually does work, it's just for some reason things got screwed up when I made an update.

Comment: I can confirm that changing the app store account to one in a different region (and language) is the (only) way I found to get to see the desired meta data on my iPhone. Just changing region/language in the phone's settings wasn't enough.